# Bootstrap grid clipping bug

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Check out the code for this
https://codepen.io/bran112299/pen/RgrGLQ

if you scroll down the text clips the nav bar
if you remove the bootstrap grid on line 13 it doesn't clip anymore

```
<p style="font-size: 30px" class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
```

Can anyone help so I can keep the bootstrap grid and have no clipping?

Comment: Note you've tagged bootstrap-4 but your example uses bootstrap-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi try this increase the z-index of nav

```
nav
{
 z-index:200;
}
```

hope this helps..